# Change php.ini values from shell script

Tags: php, shell, vagrant

I am new to shell scripts. I am running Vagrant, and find myself needing to adjust these setting in the php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize 120M
post_max_size 120M
max_execution_time 200
max_input_time 200
```

How can I add those to a shell script so I can just provision my machine on first vagrant up?

Comment: I've used `sed` for this in the past.

Answer (score 19):

with below script, you can easily adjust php.ini values. Every time, just need update top 4 lines.

make sure, your sed command supports `-i` option.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

upload_max_filesize=240M
post_max_size=50M
max_execution_time=100
max_input_time=223

for key in upload_max_filesize post_max_size max_execution_time max_input_time
do
 sed -i "s/^\($key\).*/\1 $(eval echo = \${$key})/" php.ini
done
```

Comment: please more words. a lot of people don't want to just copy paste without understading . please how to understand this `s/^\($key\).*/\1 $(eval echo \${$key})/`

Comment: It really would be nice to understand how does this works

Comment: Thanks @BMW. In my case I did `sudo sed -i "s/^\($key\).*/\1 $(eval echo \${$key})/" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

Comment: I also added an equals sign in my case for the correct php.ini syntax: `sudo sed -i "s/^\($key\).*/\1 = $(eval echo \${$key})/" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

Comment: Use sed -i with suffix to create backup file just to make sure: `sed -i.bak "s/^\($key\).*/\1 $(eval echo \${$key})/" php.ini` will create php.ini.bak

Comment: how to add date.timezone? there is dot in the name

Answer (score 3):

There is a shell script for this purpose https://github.com/StanAngeloff/vagrant-shell-scripts#php

> ```
> php-settings-update(name, value)
> ```
>
> Update a PHP setting value. This function will look for all php.ini
>   files in /etc. For each file, a conf.d directory would be created in
>   the parent directory (if one doesn't already exist) and inside a file
>   specifying the setting name/value will be placed.
>
> Example (create a default timezone):
>
> ```
> php-settings-update 'date.timezone' 'Europe/London'
> ```