# How can I edit php.ini variables with a dot in them using a shell script

Tags: php, bash, variables

I am trying to automate the configuration of opcache in php7.2.

I have a long winded script the configures the entire server, but i'm struggling to get something working to edit php.ini.

I've tried the answers found here: 
[Change php.ini values from shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23124103/change-php-ini-values-from-shell-script), but i'm not using vagrant, and the dot in the filenames is preventing me from using the settings as bash variables.

AKA this doesn't work

```
opcache.enable=1
opcache.memory_consumption=256
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=12
opcache.max_accelerated_files=16000
opcache.max_wasted_percentage=5
opcache.validate_timestamps=1
opcache.revalidate_freq=2
opcache.save_comments=0
opcache.enable_file_override=1
opcache.error_log=/var/log/php-opcache.error.log
opcache.log_verbosity_level=1


for key in opcache.enable opcache.memory_consumption yadda yadda
do
 sed -i "s/^\($key\).*/\1 $(eval echo \${$key})/" php.ini
done
```

For obvious reasons, you can't just do this at a command prompt

```
my.variableproperty=1
```

You *CAN* do this, but its not what I need

```
my_variableproperty=1
```

I have sed with -i and awk available, as well as any other command can be added if needed. This is an Ubuntu 18.04 VM with php7.2 built on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess I can do this:

```
sed -i s/opcache.enable=1/opcache.enable=0/g php.sh
```

But it seems really clunky.  I mean, I guess the opcache.enabled string will be in the file, but what if it isn't? Also, what if opcache.enable doesn't have a default value?

Also, this seems to work somewhat well:

```
sed -i 's,^opcache.enable.*$,opcache.enable=1,' php.ini
```